# SqlAlchemy, cannot retrieve the counting of a table rows

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to store the number of row of the table "computers" this way:

```
with my_db.connect() as conn:

    result = conn.execute(text("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM computers;"))

    return result
```

But when I print "result" I get:

> sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.LegacyCursorResult object

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the connection's [scalar](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=scalar#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.scalar) method:

```py
with my_db.connect() as conn:

    result = conn.scalar(text("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM computers;"))

    return result
```

`.scalar` will return the first column of the first row of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `return result.one()` to get one row of values from the result cursor